# ubuntu 16.04 upgrade problem with virtualbox

Tags: upgrade, virtualbox, dpkg

After I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 I have problems with the virtual box. Whenever I want to install something I get the following error message.

```
Setting up virtualbox (5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
insserv: script virtualbox: service vboxdrv already provided!
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-qt:

virtualbox-qt depends on virtualbox (= 5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1); however:
Package virtualbox is not configured yet.
Package virtualbox-4.3 which provides virtualbox is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-qt (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured  
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
virtualbox
virtualbox-qt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Do you have any suggestion how to solve this?

Comment: Try using `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. Also, check that you have the requested `virtualbox` package installed. Otherwise, use `sudo apt-get install virtualbox`

Answer (score 4):

Now that you are on Ubuntu 16.04, i suggest to remove and purge the old Virtualbox 5.0:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-5.0
```

and then run the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib'
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Reference: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads#Debian-basedLinuxdistributions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using Virtualbox 5.0 in Ubuntu 16.04, here is what you need to do.

First, remove the old installation of Virtualbox:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-5.0
```

Now:

1. Download Virtualbox 5.0 from the official link below:

[Virtualbox 5.0](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_5_0)

Select i386 for 32-bit, or amd64 for 64bit system.

2. After downloaded the package, click to open with Software Center/Gdebi and finally install the Virtualbox 5.0

To receive future updates and fixes for VBox 5 through Software Updater or your Package Manager, you may add the official Virtualbox repository for Linux

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian $(lsb_release -cs) contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list'
```

The command creates a separate source file for VBox and writes the repository address into it. $(lsb_release -cs) automatically detects your release name, Linux Mint and Elementary OS users have to replace it (e.g., trusty for Mint 17.x and Freya, precise for Mint 13 and Luna).

Also download and insert the keyring so that Ubuntu trusts the package from that repository:

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

Finally, you can upgrade VirtualBox as a part of system updates through Software Updater/Package Manager when a new release is out.

For those using Linux Kernel 4.8 in Ubuntu 16.04:

You will need to apply the Vitualbox patch which can be downloaded here:
[vboxhost_5.0.28r111378_kernel_4.8.2.patch](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=80263)

Put "vboxhost_5.0.28r111378_kernel_4.8.2.patch" in the Home directory.
Open the terminal (don't worry about the number, it still works).

```
cd /usr/src/vboxhost-5.0.28

sudo patch -p1 < /home/core/vboxhost_5.0.28r111378_kernel_4.8.2.patch
```

Now compile drivers into the kernel.

```
sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup
```

Virtualbox 5.0 is ready to run.